# How to use Bluetooth in C#/.net?

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth

I'm trying to do an UI with C# on Visual Studio (on PC[windows10]) and connect some bluetooth devices.
I'm using Windows.Devices.Radios & Windows.Devices.Bluetooth, but I have some troubles with that. After few steps I try to use the bluetooth when I press a button.
This is the code

```
        private async void btnStart_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Repl test = new Repl();

        var radio = await Radio.RequestAccessAsync();
        if (access != RadioAccessStatus.Allowed)
        {
            return;
        }
        BluetoothAdapter adapter = await BluetoothAdapter.GetDefaultAsync();
        if (null != adapter)
        {
            var btRadio = await adapter.GetRadioAsync();
            if (bluetoothState)
            {
                await btRadio.SetStateAsync(RadioState.On);
            }
            else
            {
                await btRadio.SetStateAsync(RadioState.Off);
            }
        }
        string connect = $"connect {macRight}\r\n";
        //string start = "start\r\n";

        await BaseCommands.repl.ParseLine(connect);

    }
```

after the 1st request I'm always in the "return;"
I saw some people saying use x32 or x64 and x86. I already try that but I don't know why it doesn't work for me ...
I also saw some post saying change something in the Manifest, but I don't know where to find it :/
I'm a beginner with C#/.NET so if someone can help me to fix that i will appreciate =)
PS : I have another project which use bluetooth and it work perfectly so I have no ideas to fix my own project ...

Comment: When this method `GetRadioAsync` is called from a desktop application (Win32), it will retrieve radio instances only when the application is natively compiled for the target architecture (in other words, when the application matches the computer architecture; so an x86 application running on an x64 architecture computer won't see any radio instances).

Comment: Where is `access` being set? You say you are always ending up at that return line, but you aren't showing any code that changes `access`

Comment: @RaoHammas Hi, I put my project in x64 for my computer, but I still don't understand why on my other project I have no trouble to use it with the source code :/
Do you know if my project will work only on x64 or I can make it change for every computer ?

Comment: @TJRockefeller You were right, I don't know why I didn't set "access", big mistake.. Now I use "access" instead of "radio".

Comment: @LudwigPOILVE it worked on x64 ? if your OS is x64 then it will work only with x64 build and if your OS is x86 then it will work only with x86 build.. The above statement meant if you are building win32 app like winform or Wpf then it depends on OS architecture. got my point ?